# oracle apex 5.0 plug-in

Tags: plugins, oracle-apex, selectlist, oracle-apex-5

I found a plug-in called Group Select List from this link yesterday:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/apex-plug-ins-182042.html#item

My problem is that I'm using APEX 5.0 and this plug in makes the select list look like one from 4.0.  So, it doesn't really look good with the other 5.0 select lists on the page.  Can someone direct me to the portion of the plug-in code where I can make this look like a 5.0 select list?  Or any kind of fix would be helpful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
/* Match new template options */
select.group_selectlist {
  width: 100%;
  height:32px;
  color: #404040;
  background-color : #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 30px 4px 7px;

  background-image:     url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% 0;
  background-size: contain;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
select.group_selectlist:focus
,select.group_selectlist:hover {
 background-color : white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the select2 plugin for multiselect in oracle apex

https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:15057067737449::::P710_PLG_ID:BE.CTB.SELECT2

i have used my project.. its working perfectly

Comment: Hi, the plug-in I have works great for what I want to do.  It's simply the look of it that I need help with.  It has the shape and look of a LOV from 4.0 so it doesn't seem to go well with the other LOVs that I have in my app.